# JUnit just log failures?

Tags: java, junit

how can I use JUnit to not terminate on assertion failures, but just log them?

My goal is to fail if log messages exist, and print them out. Because I'd like to iterate over a big list, and want to know which elements fail.

How can I force JUnit to not break on failures?

ty

Comment: that's a bad idea. once you have a failure you're likely to be in a bad state, and further failures may be more the result of that bad initial state than because of any real problem, meaning most of what you log will be useless. the point of having small test methods and having them exit on failure is so that the starting state is well-known. Consider reworking the tests so that there are more small independent tests.

Comment: I would prefer doing what @NathanHughes has suggested over any other trick to do what you want.

Comment: fully agree with @Nathan here. test MUST fail when assertions are not met.

Comment: Consider I have a list with 100 valid account numbers, and want to test which ones fail for my custom validator. I do not want to break the testmethod for the first invalid, but collect every number that is invalid, but iterate over all no matter if there are failures.

Comment: @membersound Have a look at Parameterized. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with standard JUnit, with your tests as they are. The problem is that assertXXX methods actually throw Exceptions (AssertionError), so you can't use normal asserts and resume from the point after the exception has been thrown. JUnit catches these AssertIonErrors and does the right thing.

One alternative is to use, as Ludwig suggested, the ErrorCollector rule, but it will mean rewriting a fair portion of your tests I would imagine.

If your goal is to iterate over a large list, look at [Parameterized](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html). This allows you to iterate over single test method, with different data each time:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
  @Parameters
  public static List<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
      { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }
    });
  }

  private int fInput;

  private int fExpected;

  public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
    fInput= input;
    fExpected= expected;
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
  }
}
```

data() returns a list of Object[]. Each Object[] in the list is passed to the constructor of the test class. So a new instance of the test class is used for each entry in the list.

The number of entries in the Object[] must correspond to the number of parameters to the constructor, and the types have to correspond as well.

Comment: This sound promissing. But what if I have eg 6 parameters? 3 for the input to test a method, and 3 to verify the result?

Comment: The constructor takes as many parameters as you want. You just define the appropriate number of objects in the method annotated as @Parameters, data() in the above example.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [ErrorCollector](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all the reasons a test might have failed, rather than just the first one, you need to create a list of reasons the test failed and throw an error if the list is not empty at the end.

Comment: I do this quite a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a build tool like ant with the [junit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task, there is a `haltonfailure` property that you could put to `no` so it doesn't stop your build process when a test fails.